# Resources not loading properly , images loading partially

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cloudflare

I have a site [link](http://isiddharth.com/beta). I am using cloudflare and mod_deflate to serve gzipped content.

My site works fine everywhere except on the Android Jelly Bean browser.
The fonts & images don't load properly.

Also many a times on other browsers as well, images load partially.

Can someone point out why?

Comment: I'm constantly getting half pictures in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize that this is a little older, my hunch here would be Rocket Loader or the image optimization features (possibly Mirage). Have you tried turning them of in your performance settings, if on?